# Can I use DT_STR in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I was using SSIS in which I have code that I use for parsing files with year / month and day
so in Expression Builder I use:

```
(DT_STR,4,1252)MONTH( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() )) gets the month
(DT_STR,4,1252)DAY( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() )) gets the day
(DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() )) gets the year
```

However, when I am coding, I like to paste my code into a sql server query window as well, but this DT_STR seems to be specific to SSIS ?

Is there an equivalent replacement, or why can't I use this in T-SQL?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I see now that this code is not all all portable to t-sql , nor is it used correctly with the month and day never being a length of 4

```
(DT_STR, 4, 1252) YEAR (DATEADD ( "dd", 0, getdate())) + RIGHT ("0" + LTRIM ((DT_STR, 4, 1252) MONTH (DATEADD ("dd", 0, getdate()))), 2) + RIGHT ("0" + LTRIM ((DT_STR, 4, 1252) DAY (DATEADD ("dd", -1, getdate()))), 2) + ".TXT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSIS Expression language is not TSQL. You might as well ask why can't you paste Motorola 68k assembly code into an R compiler? DT_STR is an [Integration Services Data Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx). The approximate [SQL Server data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) would be varchar(N).

If your question is how do you verify your expressions are correct, assign them to a variable and then you can inspect them during package execution by setting a breakpoint and then looking at the Locals window. The Variables window you use during development is not going to contain the *run time* values. Complex expressions built in a Task's properties is a nightmare for troubleshooting as there are no facilities to provide inspection.

Finally, your code above assigns a length of 4 to entities that will never be 4 spaces in length: month and day.